# Magento 2.3.0 WYSIWYG editor's image not loading on frontend

Tags: url, image, wysiwyg, magento2.3.0

we have created some category's custom attribute of WYSIWYG editor type. While we are adding image in these custom attribute's editor, they are showing/loading fine in admin section but while we are fetching these attributes data on frontend, images are not loading.

Magento making image url on frontend like -  `<img src="{{media url=&quot;handmade-thumb.jpg&quot;}}" alt="" />`

Its picking image url as text.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to filter that content using cms page filter.

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
) {
    $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
}
```

Now use:

```
$this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
```

Comment: Hie @Sohel Rana here $content means what?

Comment: Thanks for solution. It is working fine.